# Use local WIFI network Database from Android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, networking, wifi

I want to read a .sqlite database that i have in my Windows Pc from my app and use it there. How can i do this?
Both devices are connected to the same network by WiFi.
My app is now taking the DB from the sd card, so i have all the code for handling it. I just need to read it from my PC.
Thank you on advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make a **wrapper**. It's a proxy between your app and your DB and its job is to intercept requests from your app, make some requests on your DB then returns the result (e.g. a PHP script which receive and send JSON messages).

IMHO, it's not a good idea to deal directly with the DB (for security and fiability reasons).